# How to convert Default DateTime to DateTime Object with "dd-MMM-yyyy" format only in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datagridview

There are lot of answers available to convert DateTime Object to String Format as desired, but I want to convert DateTime to yet another DateTime Object but in format "yyyy/MM/dd" format only.

***Scenario :***

1. I am displaying Dapper's IEnumerable "Model" Class directly binded with DataGridView's DataTable. and it is displays the DateTime Field in gridview as below Image.
2. There is dynamic binding of Dapper Model with DataGridView Datasource. Nothing is pre-defined like *Column*, *alignment* and stuff.

***Expect output :*** DateTime Object with "dd-MMM-yyyy" format in it.

***Actual Output :*** DateTime Object with "MM/dd/yyyy" format in it.

------------------***UPDATED***-------------------

I have created a datatable for datetime field as below;

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Utility.getDisplayName<InvoiceItems>((int)SalesJOINCustomers.Columns.Timestamp), typeof(DateTime)));
```

and customized the field to my format;

```
gridSales.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
```

Still I same as in the image.

[image]

Comment: "Convert DateTime to another format" doesn't make any sense. You can use `DateTime.ToString` to *print* different DateTime formats, though.

Comment: How do you save it? Sure the date format in the screen isn't just different and that the actual data is okay?

Comment: DateTime does not have a format, only a value. The format is applied when displaying it, by the component that does the displaying. So in this case you'll have to look at making changes to the DataGridView column definition.

Comment: @Peter B : I have mentioned that everything is dynamic, no pre binding :)

Comment: Then you'll have to make your code smarter by inspecting which field or fields of the DataTable have a DateTime, and then making changes to the proper dynamically generated column or columns. You might also try setting global regional settings for your application in the hope that the DataGridView will use that.

Comment: Thank you all for your lighting speed replies. I'll Do it and post an answer for this query if possible.

Comment: After your update: it should work, I just tested it myself. Check that the query actually returns DateTime values, and not already-formatted-date-strings. If they are strings from the moment you receive them, then setting a format for the grid column will be ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I update the Post as [SOLVED]. Thanks Peter!

Comment: This looks like the question was edited to make it an answer; we don't do that here, since future readers will not understand the context. Would you add an answer in the answer box below? We also do not use [solved] here.

Comment: Ok @halfer , I will update the stuff in short time. Thanks.